# Inserting both a variable and multiple values into a SQL table

Tags: sql

I am storing data related to fan artworks. Three SQL tables relate to this question. The Art table contains data related to the artwork (i.e. and ArtId, URL, description). There is a Characters table that lists characters that could be in an image. The Characters table contains an Id, a character name, and the Fandom Id (which is not relevant to this question). There is an ArtCharactersBridge table which contains ArtId and CharacterId fields. When I call the function to insert into Art, I have a list of characterIds that must be inserted into the ArtCharactersBridge.

My problem is inserting into the ArtCharactersBridge. I have a user-defined table (which is a list of Ids) for the character ids, and a variable for the art id. I do not know how to insert the same art id for different character ids. Actually, I can do it, I'll put the code below, but I insert only the character ids and then update the table to add art id where it is null. This seems like it would be terribly prone to errors. I believe I can add both art id and character ids in one statement but have no idea how to do so.

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[Art_Insert]
    @url varchar(1000)
    , @date datetime
    , @description varchar(2000)
    , @artistId int
    , @characterIds dbo.udtIds READONLY

AS

BEGIN

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Art]
           ([ImageURL]
           ,[DatePosted]
           ,[Description]
           ,[ArtistId])
     VALUES
           (@url
           ,@date
           ,@description
           ,@artistId
           )

END

DECLARE
    @Id int
SET @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
INSERT INTO dbo.ArtCharactersBridge
            ([CharacterId]
            )
SELECT * FROM @characterIds

UPDATE dbo.ArtCharactersBridge SET ArtId = @id
WHERE ArtId IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INSERT INTO dbo.ArtCharactersBridge
([CharacterId], [ArtID]
)
SELECT c.ID, @id FROM @characterIds c

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you.